# User gives MXN matrix and i want to convert to numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, user-input

***Input***

```
2 3 **Here 2,3 are size of mateix m,n**
2 3 4
5 6 7
```

***output***

```
[
  [2 3 4]
  [5 6 7]
]
```

Note:-use Numpy package

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If the input matrix is in the file you can use the following program:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.loadtxt('file.txt', dtype=int, delimiter=' ') # you don't need to give the matrix size at the beginning of the file

print(x)

rows = int(input('give number of rows: '))
cols = int(input('give number of columns: '))

x = np.zeros((rows,cols), dtype=int)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        x[i,j] = int(input(f"give matrix element for row {i} and column {j}: "))
        
print(x)
```

If you want the user to input the matrix elements use the second part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Reading *m x n* input as a numpy matrix :

```py
import numpy as np
m,n = map(int, input().split())
arr = np.zeros((m,n))
for i in range(m):
    arr[i] = np.array(list(map(int, input().split())))
```

**Output :**

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```